# RouteOnAttribute based on list

Tags: apache-nifi

In my NiFi pipeline I have some flow files that ran into an issue with a Python script running on the `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor. When they fail, they come out as 0 byte flow files so I can't look and see what might be causing the issue nor how to fix it. Luckily, the flow file is not just gone forever: it exists in S3 with about 60 million other files. However, I do not want to mass re-pull from S3 and have to manually comb through to find each file that filed.

Instead, what I've concocted is that I can pull a specific id that's in the attributes of the failed, empty flow files and throw it into a list thanks to `AttributetoJSON`. What I would *like* to do is then re-pull from S3 and run those through a `RouteOnAttribute` processor that will keep flow files whose id appears in the list, and then discard those that don't. However, I'm not seeing a clear way to use the list in my `RouteOnAttribute` processor. Is there a way to do something like `${nameid} in [123, 345, 567, 789]`?

Comment: @daggett I'm not quite sure what you mean? when it comes out of the ExecuteStreamCommand as non-zero exit status it comes out as a 0 byte file.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed ExecuteScript and ExecuteCommand. To match multiple values, you could use match function like this: `${myattr:matches('^(123|345|678)$')}`

Comment: @daggett Gotcha, was wondering if I had seriously missed something major. Thank you, that looks perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `in` function that exactly match with your case. Check the [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#in).

```
${nameid:in(123,345,567,789)}
```